# What is the execution order of Multiple Pipeline Behaviors in MediatR

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, mediatr

Let's say I have these behaviors in `MediatR` in my `ConfigureServices` class in `.NET6`:

```
        services.AddMediatR(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
        services.AddTransient(typeof(IPipelineBehavior<,>), typeof(UnhandledExceptionBehaviour<,>));
        services.AddTransient(typeof(IPipelineBehavior<,>), typeof(AuthorizationBehaviour<,>));
        services.AddTransient(typeof(IPipelineBehavior<,>), typeof(ValidationBehaviour<,>));
        services.AddTransient(typeof(IPipelineBehavior<,>), typeof(PerformanceBehaviour<,>));
```

And this behavior is supposed to be executed before the all concrete `CommandHandler` which implemented `IRequestHandler`.

So what is the execution order of these behaviors? How can I set priority for the execution of the behaviors?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Being a beginner in `mediatR` stuff, I get that the order of execution of these behaviors comes from registering order these services in `ConfigureServices` or whatever you call this in your Application.
for that matter in your case, the order of execution of these behaviors will be:

```
Exception >> Authorization >> Validation >> Performance.
```

But if change the registration order in configure services i.e registering `UnhandledExceptionBehaviour` in second place and Authorization in the first place.

```
    services.AddTransient(typeof(IPipelineBehavior<,>), typeof(AuthorizationBehaviour<,>));
    services.AddTransient(typeof(IPipelineBehavior<,>), typeof(UnhandledExceptionBehaviour<,>));
    services.AddTransient(typeof(IPipelineBehavior<,>), typeof(ValidationBehaviour<,>));
    services.AddTransient(typeof(IPipelineBehavior<,>), typeof(PerformanceBehaviour<,>));
```

The execution order then will be as below:

```
Authorization >> Exception >> Validation >> Performance
```

There is `IRequestPreProcessor`,`PostProcessor` which is also very useful in `MediatR` that is executed before/after the request execution.